# MVC WebAPI with SPA

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, breeze, single-page-application

I am new to the WebAPI.  I have 4 entities:

1. Location
2. Service
3. Item
4. Application

I have read several WebAPI tutorials.  They all seem to have CRUD methods in each API Controller that deals with single entity.  One functionality that I need is to simulate cascade dropdown and cascade update where Location determines range of Service.  Each Service determines list of Service Item.  Each Item may be used in a list of Application.  The question is

1. Do I create 4 API Controllers with CRUD methods?
2. I need all 4 objects on one form as List Boxes that allow multi-selection.
3. Along side the 4 List Boxes, how to show a list of combination of selected value that are saved to a database table?
4. Which javascript library or framework is the best for SPA (Single Page App)?  I am currently leaning towards Backbone.js and HotTowel.js.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could expose your service as an [OData service](http://www.odata.org/). If you wish to support filtering, then you should use the separate [OData NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.odata), and [develop your controllers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/01/29/getting-started-with-asp-net-webapi-odata-in-3-simple-steps.aspx). In this case four controllers would suit.

Then, you can use a client side rich data library such as [breeze.js](http://www.breezejs.com/) to make building requests to the OData service straightforward. You would then use an [MV* client side framework](http://todomvc.com/) to provide two way bindings between the client side view models and the UI elements.

Hot Towel isn't a JavaScript library, it's a Visual Studio extension which allows you to create a new project as a starting point for your SPA. The template requires Visual Studio 2012 and the ASP.NET Web Tools 2012.2 update.

It uses breeze.js, [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) for the binding, and [Durandal.js](http://durandaljs.com/) for navigation, life cycle, and view composition.